# Wordpress upgraded to 4.2.2 and all the jquery and javascript stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, upgrade

I am really stucked over here.
[enter link description here](http://cannarxcard.com/)

This is the site. I was working on it last night. I did't change anything. I was just uploading some banner images and when I refreshed, all the buttons, modals or any other places where javascript or jquery was used stopped working. Can you please suggest a fix?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are errors reported in your browser console, for starters?

Comment: Can you please check. I dont know how to do that. I'll ve very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: The site you linked seems to work just fine. To open the browser console, hit `F12`.  That's a basic tool for web development.

Comment: Actually, the website is working fine. If you click the buttons, or the search icon on the right, its not working.

Comment: Also, the mobile menu is not loading. If you contract the browser, the mobile menu wont load.

Comment: There's a broken `</style>` tag in the document somewhere; it's `</style` without the `>`. That may be causing serious problems.

Comment: Ok. Let me check. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you have <?php wp_footer(); ?> in your theme footer.php. I cannot see the bootstrap.js loaded, so that is why your menu do not work...

Comment: Thanks alot sir. You rock. You saved my breath. I dont know how to thank you.

Comment: One favour more please. Can you please tell me how did you find that it was a missing </style tag? I will be very grateful.